# CXF Web Service JMX Port Assignment

Tags: java, cxf, jmx, jconsole

We have many CXF web services running under Tomcat. For each of the services, there is a beans config file, with each one having an entry like the one below. The variable ${JMX.PORT} is replaced with the assigned port at runtime. Each service has a separate port. I have looked everywhere but cannot confirm that this is correct. I do know, however, that having the same port for two or more services causes startup issues. So, I am looking for confirmation that each service should have its own port. Note - When I look at a service remotely using JConsole, with a connection string such as **service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi:/192.168.29.35:9912/jmxrmi**, I can also see the *other* services, even though they have different port assignments. That makes no sense, unless there are some kind of shared resources. Can anyone help me to understand this? Thanks!

```
    <bean id="org.apache.cxf.management.InstrumentationManager" class="org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl">

<property name="bus" ref="cxf" /> 
<property name="enabled" value="true" />
<property name="threaded" value="false" /> 
<property name="daemon" value="false" /> 
<property name="usePlatformMBeanServer" value="true"/> 
<property name="JMXServiceURL" value="service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:${JMX.PORT}/jmxrmi" /> 

    </bean>
```